# How to calculate subtotals and add it to the same dataframe?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (the first 15 rows), which I named "tableIOPT":

```
        IO                                          PT          FA  FR
    1   não-orientado_gerúndio                      forma-base  0   0%
    2   não-orientado_infinitivo                    forma-base  0   0%
    3   não-orientado_particípio_masculino          forma-base  0   0%
    4   orientado_finito_passado_imperfectivo       forma-base  0   0%
    5   orientado_finito_passado_perfectivo_I       forma-base  0   0%
    6   orientado_finito_passado_volitivo           forma-base  1   100%
    7   orientado_finito_presente                   forma-base  0   0%
    8   orientado_não-finito_imperativo_I           forma-base  0   0%
    9   orientado_não-finito_subjuntivo_condicional forma-base  0   0%
    10  orientado_não-finito_subjuntivo_conjuntivo  forma-base  0   0%
    11  ZERO                                        forma-base  3   27.27%
    12  não-orientado_gerúndio                      modal       0   0%
    13  não-orientado_infinitivo                    modal       0   0%
    14  não-orientado_particípio_masculino          modal       0   0%
    15  orientado_finito_passado_imperfectivo       modal       0   0%
```

And I need to calculate subtotals on column "FA" by groups on column "PT". For example: there are 4 "forma-base" in total.

I'm no expert, but I know it's not difficult to simply calculate subtotals. I used margin.table(tabelaIOPT,2) and it shows the results perfectly. The problem is I will do some statistical testing later, and I need those subtotals in the same dataframe.

This is what I've already tried:

```
    for (i in length(subtotals))    {
    tableIOPT[grep(names(subtotals)[i],tableIOPT[,2]),5] <- subtotals[i]
                                    }
```

Those "subtotals" are simply (when it was a table, before I made it into a dataframe):

```
    subtotals <- margin.table(tableIOPT,2)
```

And tableIOPT in particular has 99 rows. But I have a LOT of other dataframes with the same configuration.

The expected results in this case are: "4, 4, 7, 10, 7, 19, 13, 2, 6" for "forma-base, modal, não-orientado_gerúndio, não-orientado_infinitivo, não-orientado_particípio, orientado_finito_passado, orientado_finito_presente, orientado_não-finito_imperativo, ZERO", respectively.

That's why I'm adding a fifth column at the end and trying to "paste" the results there. However, this loop is only working for the last element of the subtotals vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table), you could sum by group as

```r
library(data.table)
# turn your data.frame into a data.table
tableIOPT <- setDT(tableIOPT)
# add a column subtot, containing the original number of rows
tableIOPT <- tableIOPT[, subtot := sum(FA), by = "PT"]
# or simply the subtotals per group
tableIOPT[, list(subtot = sum(FA)), by = "PT"]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
tableIOPT %>%
    group_by(PT) %>%
    mutate(subtotals = sum(FA))
```

Comment: Please add `ungroup` at the end.

Comment: Great, Please accept the answer if it addresses your need.